# Test if string in n positions of alphabet

Tags: r

As the title suggests, I am looking for an elegant* way to test whether a character is in the first n positions in the alphabet.

So, for a character vector as follows: 
`names <- c("Brian", "Cormac", "Zachariah")`
And with `n <- 6`
It would return:
`TRUE','TRUE', 'FALSE'`

*I am aware that I can use `substr(names,1,1) %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")`, but I was hoping for a better solution.

EDIT: What I mean by position in the alphabet is whether the first letter is in the first n letters in alphabetical order. So, "A" is in the first n = 1+, "B" is in the first n =2+, "Y" in the first n=25 letters, etc.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by elegant, how about this: `substring(names, 1, 1) %in% LETTERS[1:6]`

Comment: Another possibility: `substr(names, 1, 1) < LETTERS[n+1]`

Comment: Since you are checking for all 1-6 letters you can as well do `names<="F"`

Comment: Just beware that `"'" < "F"` and `"9" < "F"` evaluates to `TRUE`

Comment: That solution by PoGibas looks perfect, thank you! I'll mark it as answered if you want to post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

PoGibas comment seems to have as elegant as it gets. Next step would be wrapping it in a function:

```
cht6_pog <- function(string) {
  x <- toupper(substring(string, 1, 1)) %in% LETTERS[1:6]
  names(x) <- string
  x
}

cht6_pog(names)
Brian    Cormac Zachariah 
 TRUE      TRUE     FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for your question.

```
# fun:    
check_char <- function(string, start_n, end_n, char_pattern)
{
  str_list <- strsplit(substr(string, start_n, end_n), "")
  out <- sapply(str_list, function(x) any(tolower(x) %in% tolower(char_pattern)))
  return(out)
}

# args:
str_vec <- c("Google", "Facebook", "Amazon")
str_n <- 1
end_n <- 4
char <- LETTERS[1:6]

# run:
out <- check_char(str_vec, str_n, end_n, char)
print(out)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```